# Links as Variables in other File

Tags: php, html, css

my problem is that i have a navbar and need to put i on each page.
So Home, Profile, Search, Add have the same navbar fixed in bottom.

Now i want to save the links to the page in a diffrent file.

So something like:

```
    <div class="botnav">
  <a class="active" href="links.php?$homelink">Home</a>
  <a href="links.php?$profilelink">Profile</a>
  <a href="links.php?$searchlink">Search</a>
  <a href="links.php?$addlink">Add</a>
</div>
```

is this even possbile with GET or POST?

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you want to make a templating framework? Basic way to do this is with [Include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) Though there are more sophisticated ways of this sort of thing. Consider using an established framework (e.g. Laravel)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a page with your code:

header.php

```
<div class="botnav">
  <a class="active" href="links.php?$homelink">Home</a>
  <a href="links.php?$profilelink">Profile</a>
  <a href="links.php?$searchlink">Search</a>
  <a href="links.php?$addlink">Add</a>
</div>
```

In each page you can call that with

```
<?php include ('header.php'); ?>
```

Comment: update bottom code snippet to `<?php include('header.php'); ?>` with the parentheses as a suffix to `include()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already tried this and it works with the menu. But then i have to do it without an active icon. Beacuse when i include it in the head.php i active on every page the same icon

Answer (score 0):

The way I include a nav menu to be used on different pages is with PHP's include statement `include()`.

```
<?php include("path_to_header"); ?>
```

What I recommend is to create a few extra files: `path.php` and `header.php` to hold your nav menu.

The path.php file should be located in the root of your project so that `__FILE__` provides the actual root project path.

```
<?php
define("ROOT_PATH", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
?>
```

Next, handle the header being in a separate file `header.php` for reference.

```
<div class="botnav">
    <a class="active" href="links.php?$homelink">Home</a>
    <a href="links.php?$profilelink">Profile</a>
    <a href="links.php?$searchlink">Search</a>
    <a href="links.php?$addlink">Add</a>
</div>
```

Then in each of your pages `include()` the `path.php` file and also the `header.php` with another include statement where ever you choose.

```
<?php include("path.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>El test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Include header file where you need -->
        <?php include(ROOT_PATH . "/header.php"; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already tried this and it works with the menu. But then i have to do it without an active icon. Beacuse when i include it in the head.php i active on every page the same icon

Comment: @MoritzKosubek Update the `element:active` with CSS